Analysing answers: why the first sentence is true and the second - false?
∀x∃y R(x,y), ∃x∀y R(x,y)
There is an interpretation example, which makes first sentence true and the second false:
Domäne: 0, 1
R(x,y): ⟨0, 1⟩, ⟨1, 0⟩
I do not understand why the second sentence is false.
∀x∃y R(x,y), ∀x∃y R(y,x)
There is an interpretation example, which makes first sentence true and the second false:
domain: 0, 1
R(x,y): ⟨0, 0⟩, ⟨0, 1⟩.
Here is the same. The second is for me true, and with the first sentence I also have problems.

I also agree that, for your second $R(x,y): \langle 0,0\rangle, \langle 0,1\rangle$, the second sentense $\forall x \exists y\ R(y,x)$ is true.

In your first example, the relation on the domain $\{0, 1\}$ may be defined by $R(x, y) \iff x = 1 - y$. $\exists x \forall y . x = 1 - y$ is false on this domain: each element of $\{0, 1\}$ is related to exactly one element, so there cannot be an $x$ that is related to both of the elements.
In your second example, the relation may be defined by $R(x, y) \iff x = 0$. On the domain $\{0, 1\}$ $\forall x \exists y. x = 0$ is false (do you see why?), while, as you say, $\forall x \exists y. y = 0$ is true.
